# How do I make an extensible engine in XNA?

Tags: xna

I making a new engine for my game, based on the component system. Every game object is a set of some components, like render, physics, AI, etc. I want to make my game extensible; I now how to make a plugin system with .NET, but how do I make my game able to add new resources from plugins, at runtime? How should such the plugin that stores content look? I want to make simple system, like *"Total Annihilation"* has, to be able to add new units.

Comment: You might want to add what systems you are targeting (PC, 360, Phone7) since that has a big impact on what libraries you can use.

Comment: PC , and mayby xbox, but I don't know how plugin system can look on xbox, is it posible ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create as many instances of `ContentManager` as you like. Just create a new instance for each plugin and set its root directory to something specific to that plugin.

For example, you could organise your plugin directory like this:

```
Plugins
|
+- TotallyCoolPlugin
   |
   +- TotallyCoolPlugin.dll
   |
   +- Content
      |
      +- TotallyCoolImage.xnb
```

Presumably your plugin will have some kind of plugin object that you can use reflection to find and instance. Tell it its base path, so then you can have it create a content manager (or something like this - it depends on your implementation). For example:

```
[PluginMainClass]
public class MyTotallyCoolPlugin : Plugin
{
    public override void LoadPlugin(string basePath)
    {
        ContentManager content = new ContentManager();
        content.RootDirectory = Path.Combine(basePath, @"Content");
    }
}
```

Once you have something like this working, you could expand it with other clever things. One possible example is to use [`ResourceContentManager`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb198710(v=xnagamestudio.42)) to embed your content in the DLL itself. Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/06/12/embedding-content-as-resources.aspx) and [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110307192132/http://forums.create.msdn.com:80/forums/t/36049.aspx).